# Button image cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I added a dropdown button with a down arrow (image) with the help of https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp. However, after adding the down arrow image, the image area of the button cannot be clicked? Not quite sure what went wrong here, the button is still functional.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function dropdownMenu() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }</script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- dropdown feature -->
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="dropdownMenu()" class="dropbtn">User

            <!--image cant be clicked???-->
            <img src="images.png" style="height:8px; width:10px; margin-bottom: 2px; margin-left: 5px;">

        </button>

        <!-- dropdown content -->
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a>
            <a href="settings.html">Settings</a>
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: -69.5px;
    left: 1280px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 90px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 1210px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 164px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

Can someone please help identify what is the error here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Everything looks right to me.. I even tested it and it works just fine for me.. https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/povxBgY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `pointer-events: none` css property to the `i` tag element:

```
.fa {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

to prevent any pointer events for the `<i>` tag

Live Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/devmahmoudfawzy/pen/BayqEzV)